# unresolved import "include" and "url"

Tags: python, django, eclipse, google-app-engine

Within my project package's settings.py (`/projectname/projectname/settings.py`), Eclipse is giving me "unresolved import: include" and "unresolved import: url" for the following line:

`from django.conf.urls import include, url`

`include` and `url` are both underlined with a red squiggly.

Strangely, I am still able to run this application and deploy it to Google App Engine. I have tried cleaning the project, but Eclipse still gives me this error.

At the moment I'm not sure what other pertinent information to include. I am getting no error messages when running the application. The Django welcome screen shows up as normal....

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: If the project run normally, there's no problem. I think Eclipse IDE is wrong configured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project's properties, find `PyDev - PYTHONPATH > External Libraries > External Source Folders > Add source folder`

You can then add the path to google_appengine's django folder. Eg:

```
/path/to/google_appengine/lib/django...
```

Then restart: `File > Restart`

Comment: Beautiful! That worked excellently, thank you sir. That's really weird, though. Upon my project creation I already included my entire `google_appengine/lib` folder. Nonetheless, this worked splendidly. Great answer.